# Is it possible to use Ionic framework for part of the UI in an existing jQuery mobile app?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile, ionic-framework

I'm a developer who has been working with React for a bit, and now I'm being tasked with adding some features to an existing mobile application.

The existing application uses jQuery Mobile and phonegap, but I've been told I should use the Ionic framework (http://ionicframework.com/) for the new piece I'm building. The new piece is a self-contained area of the app that won't need to interact with the rest of the app.

Is this possible? From what I can tell, Ionic is focused on simplifying cross-platform development from the top level, and so an entire "project" could use the Ionic framework, but using Ionic just to create a component that needs to fit into a different project might not be easy (or even possible).

Are there other alternative technologies I should investigate?

Comment: Hi Erlloyd, I suggest you to create new Ionic application with existing application build id.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you still need to build all application with ionic to make it work which means it's a poor idea. If existing application use phonegap, you can easily build some fancy UI using frameworks well known in web technology. There are some positivies of using ionic (DOM nodes recycling) but still, you need to build module that will fit, not an entire app.

Answer (score 0):

use http://framework7.io/ it uses a jquery like syntax with awesome UI

Comment: While this may be a good framework, I was told to use Ionic, so I'm just trying to gather data right now on the feasibility of the suggested approach.